# How to prevent using the connection after close() method explicitly called on the connection object?

Tags: connection-pooling

The question can be rephrased to how to prevent a user(thread) who returned the connection to the pool by calling `close()` but still has the reference to the connection object from reusing the connection without getting the connection out from the connection pool?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? SQL server really is the one that manages the connections here from its pool.

Comment: consider it as an interview question

Comment: Did my answer helped? am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Simply follow the rule of always get connection from connection pool when you **need** or about to use it, and **always** close it when finished.

Try with resources block can help you achieve it.

```
 try (Connection conn=connectionPool.getConnection()) {
```